# Understanding the math behind perspective matrix in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, perspective

I've been trying to figure out the math behind perspective matrix for 2 weeks now but I'm failing badly. I understand the theory behind the perspective matrix but I am not sure how the math works.

**The code:**

```scala
def perspective(fov: Float, aspect: Float, zNear: Float, zFar: Float) = {
  val h = Math.tan(fov * 0.5f).toFloat
  val c00 = 1.0f / (h * aspect)
  val c11 = 1.0f / h
  val c22 = (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar)
  val c23 = (zFar + zFar) * zNear / (zNear - zFar)

  Matrix4(
    c00,    0,      0,     0,
    0,    c11,      0,     0,
    0,      0,    c22,   c23,
    0,      0,     -1,     0
  )
}
```

### What I understand

I've seen video tutorials by [Jorge Rodriguez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dul0mui292Q&list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My&index=44) & [Arpan Pathak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jmiXZlacx0&ab_channel=ArpanPathakArpanPathak) but I cannot fully relate it to the perspective matrix in the function above.

- **Congruent triangles**: Following [Arpan's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jmiXZlacx0&ab_channel=ArpanPathakArpanPathak) video I understand that to project a point P=(x, y, z) onto the a 2D `XY` plane I need to create a frustum and which is then used to find it's projection P<sup>'</sup>=(x<sup>'</sup>, y<sup>'</sup>, z<sup>'</sup>) using congruent triangles relationship. Arpan's video and the final matrix makes sense but I do not see how it relates to the perspective function above? Here is my attempt.
- [image]
- Following the above I switched the frustum in opposite direction to visualise how it would apply in OpenGL using the perspective function above with `zFar` and `zNear` parameters but it's no way close to the perspective matrix in the code.
- [image]

Comment: I worked it out from this link. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: I'm unable to follow. I feel like it lacks explanation on the math.

Answer (score 1):

Your `h` at the bottom is missing the left/right and top/bottom parameters; cf.
to the code at the top where they are expressed as angle `fov` and aspect
ratio.

Thanks to the `1` in the w-row of the matrix you get the `z` value as 4th
coordinate, because this is the other parameter for the new `x` and `y` values.
A high `x` (same for `y`) value at large distance/depth shall be displayed near the center.

The idea of the perspective projection is to choose a frustum and turn it into
a cube ranging from -1 to 1 in all 3 dimensions - the NDC coordinates.

So for `x` and `y` the relation is:

Xndc = h * X / Z

This divide by `Z` cannot be expressed in a matrix and is done separately. `h`
stands for the width and heigth of the near plane.

The depth `Zndc` is normalized between the near and far plane. If it is done linearly you get `A*z + B = 0`, with `A*near + B = -1` and `A*far + B = 1`.

But depth wants to be stored non-linearly, with more precision at the near side. So the general equation is `(A*z+B)/z`, or `A + B/z`. And again you can define the two planes:

```
-1 = A + B/near
 1 = A + B/far
```

Now A and B have to be expressed in terms of near and far.

`A = 1 - B/f` into first equation -->

```
-1 = 1 - B/f + B/n           minus one

-2 = -B/f + B/n              multiply by f*n

-2fn = -Bn + Bf              factor out B

B(f-n) = -2fn                divide by f-n    

B = -2fn / (f-n)
```

And this `B` is exactly your `c23`, with signs and subtraction reversed. `A` is even easier to calculate.

For the matrix, `A + B/z` is not possible, so we have to switch to the `(A*z+B)/z` form with extra divide by z as for x and y.

Putting it together gives

```
Zndc = ( Z*(f+n)/(f-n) - 2fn/(f-n) )  /  Z
```

where the linear part `Z*A + B` is done by the matrix and `W` is assumed to be one so `B` is really a constant.

This brings me back to the lone "1", or rather "-1" ??, on the bottom row of the matrix. But here is my Frustum matrix, in glsl column-major (sigh) layout:

```
/* Frustum with aspect ratio */
double fside = 1 / u.frhtan);
double pldiff = u.frf - u.frn;
mat4 F = {
    vec4(fside, 0,        0, 0),
    vec4(0, fside*u.aspr, 0, 0),
    vec4(0, 0,           (u.frf + u.frn) / pldiff, 1),
    vec4(0, 0,           -2*u.frf*u.frn  / pldiff, 0)
};
```

What I changed is 1) diff is positive ie. far - near 2) "-1" is "1" 3) "2fn" is "-2fn".

This avoids the ominous Z-flip and seems to work without needing `glDepthRange` or `glDepthFunc`. It uses directly A and B as derived above (B at least I showed).

So the "lone 1" is the matrix field that stores the original z as w-value, because x, y and z all need that division to become NDC.

Where you have "0 0 -1 0" for z it should be "0 0 A B" in terms of near and far plane. Z needs to be scaled, just like X and Y, not flipped.